# Etymology of words spelt with ô

Tags: étymologie, phonétique

I was wondering whether there is a common factor in the etymology of words such as fantôme, symptôme, Rhône etc. Does the circumflex tend to indicate for instance that a letter has been dropped in modern French, or perhaps that the term derives from a Latin word with a particular ending, or some other particular feature? If so, is hôpital an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circumflex accent on o can find a justification in a question of [pronunciation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_circonflexe_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Modification_du_timbre_des_voyelles): o should then be pronounced /o/.

> Dans des mots empruntés au grec, il note sporadiquement la présence d’un oméga (ω) dans le mot quand le o se prononce [o] (bien qu’oméga ait été prononcé [ɔ], c’est-à-dire /o/ long ouvert, en grec) : diplôme (de δίπλωμα), cône (κῶνος). La règle n'est pas cohérente puisque l'on trouve des mots d'origine grecque sans le circonflexe, comme axiome (ἀξίωμα), qui se prononce bien [aksjom]. Du reste, si le mot hérité du grec n'a pas gardé un [o], l'accent n'est pas utilisé : comédie [kɔmedi] (de κωμῳδία).

The etymology from the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fant%C3%B4me) does confirm that the use of the accent for the word "fantôme" concerns  the pronunciation but the primary reason for it remains unsure (whether indicating the ancient French "au" or an s in the Greek "phantasma", it is not known).

> Prononc. et Orth. : []. Enq. : /, (D)/. Ds Ac. 1694-1932. L'éd. de 1740 signale : ,,Quelques-uns écrivent, phantôme``, mais FÉR. 1768 et FÉR. Crit. t. 2 1787 jugent l'orth. étymol. hors d'usage pour tous les mots qui dérivent de fantôme. La tendance est d'étendre à toute la famille du mot l'accent circonflexe qui rappelle que l'on a remplacé l'anc. -au- de fantauma par -o- (cf. BUBEN 1935, § 42). Bien que d'apr. DUPRÉ 1972, p. 977 cet accent remplace simplement l'anc. s de phantasma, fantasme et fantôme étant 2 doublets. Cet accent sur le mot préserve, en tout cas, le timbre fermé de la voyelle. Étymol. et Hist. 1. 1160 « image trompeuse, illusion » (Enéas, 2416 ds T.-L. : Iluec et un arbre branchu, Molt ancïen, lait et mossu, Les foilles pendeient de songes, De fantosmes et de mençonges); 2. 1165 « apparition surnaturelle » (Guillaume d'Angleterre, éd. Wilmotte, 105). Du ionien *phantagma (gr. « apparition, vision; image offerte à l'esprit par un objet; spectre fantôme » transcrit dans le lat. impérial phantasma), d'où *phantauma, par altération massaliotte, le mot ayant été véhiculé dans le lat. de Gaule par l'intermédiaire de Marseille (FEW t. 8, p. 364b). Fréq. abs. littér. : 2 732. Fréq. rel. littér. : XIXe s. : a) 3 901, b) 4 024; XXe s. : a) 3 138, b) 4 245.

It can also be justified by a dropped s; in the following words a [dropped s](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_circonflexe_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Disparition_d'un_ancien_s) is the reason for the accent.

- côte, hôtel, Pentecôte, hôpital,

As an interesting digression here is the reason for the the s remaining and being pronounced in English, whereas it is not so in the corresponding word in French.

> Il convient de noter que dans de nombreux mots anglais empruntés au normand (et parfois revenus au français plus tard), un s devant une consonne sourde se prononce, au contraire de l'étymon français : forest ~ forêt, feast ~ fête, beast ~ bête, hospital ~ hôpital, etc. En effet, ces mots ont été apportés en Angleterre lors des conquêtes de Guillaume le Conquérant (bataille de Hastings, 1066) à une époque où ils se prononçaient encore en français. L'anglais n'ayant pas connu l'amuïssement, la consonne est restée.

In some cases there is no precise justification for this accent ([The Free encyclopedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_circonflexe_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Autres_cas)); it is  suspected for some words that the primary aim was to make the word more prestigious; this is true for the next two.

- prône, trône,

Other cases suggest a mere process of imitation.

- "drôle" has an accent through the process of imitation of "rôle".

The accent for the word "Rhône" is [not explained](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?t=53269).

> « Le Rhône, cité également par César sous la forme Rhodanus, semble avoir emprunté sa graphie Rh- à une ancienne forme grecque. On s’accorde à voir dans ce nom un radical hydronomique *rod- d’origine préceltique, dont le sens serait « couler », avec un suffixe prélatin -anum. Curieusement, le nom Roanne*, sous-préfecture de la Loire, semble avoir été à l’origine un nom de cours d’eau et représente lui aussi le radical préceltique *rod-. Il est cité au IIe siècle apr. J-C. par l’astronome et géographe grec Ptolémée sous la forme Rodoumna, nom qu’on retrouve dans la Table de Peutinger, carte des voies de l’Empire romain rédigée probablement au IIIe siècle ap. J-C. ; et dont nous est parvenue une copie allemande du XIIIe siècle, sous la forme Roidomna qui contient le même suffixe -onna que le nom de la Saône (et celui de la Garonne). On retrouve d’ailleurs dans le nom Rhodon, affluent qui se jette dans la Loire à Roanne, graphié anciennement Rodon ce même radical *rod- aux origines lointaines. »